# "Filled in for someone" meaning

Tags: meaning, idioms

What does **filled in for someone** mean exactly?

An example of a sentence with the idiom:

> While you were off, I *filled in for you*.

Does it mean the author of that sentence *took over my duties entirely while I was off* or *he was helping out (not much) with some of my duties*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It would normally depend on the person, however it would normally mean that they did most, if not all, of the persons duties.

If someone is 'filling in for someone' they are taking over for them, as much as they can, as a favour to the person.

It means that they do all of the other persons duties, that they have the skills to do.

Answer (score 4):

*Filled in* means he took your place.

Like a hole in the wall, you'd *fill it in* with plaster.

Whether he undertook all of your duties is questionable, it depends on what skill sets he has in comparison to yours, but most likely simply handled the day to day items and left the rest for your return.